# How to show newly added data in table in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am just creating some a mock application with some basic data a List in the controller being used. A table on the view showing basic hardcoded data in the List. There is a button that triggers a popup for a form for a new entry into the data. I use a javascript to call an action method in the controller and I have a program print in the Debug log to make sure the function is being called and the new object is being created which it is. But I can't figure out how to show the newly added data to the table.

Based on the code I thought the submit button click function would recall index and since the list is not full it would simply return the view after added the new data and show it in the table.

Controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if (areas.Count == 0)
    {
        addData();
    }

    return View(areas);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitButtonClick(string newArea, string newZone, string newAC, string newCity, string newRegion)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Area: " + newArea + ", Zone: " + newZone + ", newAC: " + newAC + ", newCity: " + newCity + ", newRegion: " + newRegion );
    areas.Add(new Areas
    {
        area = newArea,
        zone = Int32.Parse(newZone),
        areaCommunity = newAC,
        city = newCity,
        region = newRegion
    });

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After add: " + areas[areas.Count-1].area);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

The script code in View

```
    $('#subButton').click(function () {
        $.post('/Home/SubmitButtonClick', { newArea: $('#inputArea').val(), newZone: $('#inputzone').val(), newAC: $('#inputCommunity').val(), newCity: $('#inputCity').val(), newRegion: $('#inputRegion').val() });
        $('#createModal').modal('hide');
    });
```

Comment: you should add addData() method and cshtml to question

Answer (score 0):

Here: return RedirectToAction("Index", area);

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitButtonClick(string newArea, string newZone, string 
     newAC, string newCity, string newRegion)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Area: " + newArea + ", Zone: " + newZone + ", newAC: " + newAC + ", newCity: " + newCity + ", newRegion: " + newRegion );
        areas.Add(new Areas
        {
            area = newArea,
            zone = Int32.Parse(newZone),
            areaCommunity = newAC,
            city = newCity,
            region = newRegion
        });



        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After add: " + areas[areas.Count- 
   1].area);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", area);
     }
```

Here: public IActionResult Index(List area)

```
     public IActionResult Index(List<Area> area)
    {
        if (areas.Count == 0)
        {
            addData();
        }
        return View(areas);
    }


In your view, if are using strong typed view, surround your inputs and fields with this:
if(Model != null)
{
 //Yours form, fields and inputs here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add callback function in subButton click event (In script code View).

When you get data from the controller you can save it in div

If you already had any table display div then replace id of that div in following code instead of #tableview else create new div in your view where the button placed.`<div id="tableview"></div>`

```
$('#subButton').click(function () {
    $.post('/Home/SubmitButtonClick', 
    { 
        newArea: $('#inputArea').val(),
        newZone: $('#inputzone').val(),
        newAC: $('#inputCommunity').val(),
        newCity: $('#inputCity').val(),
        newRegion: $('#inputRegion').val()
    },
    function(data)
    {
        $("#tableview").html(data);
    }
    );
    $('#createModal').modal('hide');
});
```